# .htaccess 301 redirect regular expression from DotNetNuke to Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm moving an old DotNetNuke site to Wordpress and though the old site is really crappy architecture and crashes on a regular basis - the site has a fair amount of SEO cred. So, I don't want to lose anything, but the regular expression is killing me for the .htaccess-based 301 redirect.

Here's an example of an old domain post:

http://yoursite.com/tabid/57/listid/4379/Home++Garden/Life+in+Shambles+How+to+Be+Organized.aspx

Here's how the new one looks:

http://newsite.com/tgesting-new-functionality/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm helping a friend on the site (it's not mine) and I don't want to set him back at all and I'm not great with the RegExs.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the content already imported and url structure defined??

Comment: @QQQ Yes - I'm sorry about that. All of the content is important and the URL structure is now defined. From the above example, that post name is "Life in Shambles How to Be Organized." With the new URL structure, it will be "life-in-shambles-how-to-be-organized."

Comment: Well, catching the part between the last `/` and the suffix `.aspx` is fairly easy – but “translating” it to lower-case is beyond the capability of a RewriteRule (it would be possible with `RewriteMap`, but that is not available in .htaccess context), and translating all spaces to dashes is also not that trivial. You might be better of with setting up a script that gets passed everything that isn’t caught by the new rewriting structure, and then does the redirect itself after the necessary string manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For redirect

```
http://yoursite.com/tabid/57/listid/4379/Home++Garden/Life+in+Shambles+How+to+Be+Organized.aspx
```

to

```
http://newsite.com/life-in-shambles-how-to-be-organized/
```

You must set in server config at virtual host configuration

```
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

In your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "[A-Z]"
RewriteRule "(.*)" "${lowercase:$1}" [NC]
RewriteRule /([^/+]+)\.aspx http://newsite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteMap` directive defines a Rewriting Map which can be used inside rule substitution.

`RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]` Replace all + by -

`RewriteRule "(.*)" "${lowercase:$1}" [NC]` Transform to lowercase

`RewriteRule /([^/+]+)\.aspx http://newsite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]` Do the redirection

If you need replace consecutives + by a single -, just use `RewriteRule ^([^+]*)[+]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]` instead `RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]`

Comment: You will need to create another RewriteMap to take care of all the `+` into `-` as yours will only do that for the first 2.

Comment: Great Prix! It may be another form. It is not necessary. The first rewrite make a redirection (L set it as last rule when match found) loop until all + was replaced. But using a RewriteMap for this could be a better server performance

Comment: Having it do several redirects is simple not a good way to do it as there are several things you will have to consider including memory, performance, amount of redirects and limits, replacing double plus signs into single ones or rather following your example double dash into single dash since it will convert all, etc which is why I did not consider this an option even with `RewriteMap` I think the overall load for this job would not be suitable.

Comment: May be, but a htaccess-based 301 redirect solution was requested and this code works fine for the case example provided

Comment: Indeed as long as the last part of the URL doesn't have double plus sign and the user have access to the server config it should work just fine

Comment: If it is necessary, just use

RewriteRule ^([^+]*)[+]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L] 

and all consecutives + will be replaced by a single -

Comment: Thank you @mabarroso this helped save me a ton of time!